# BLDC motor waveforms

Tags: atmega, pwm, driver, brushless-dc-motor, waveform

I'm trying to drive a brushless motor (BLDC) with an ATMEGA328p
I use Timer0/1/2 to generate 3 different PWMs @ 62Khz.
First I tried (only absolute values)

$$A = \sin(T)$$

$$B = \sin\left(T + \frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$

$$C = \sin\left(T + \frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$$

But the angular speed was "pulsing" so I tried to generate 3 triangular signals 
$$\text{space by} \frac{2\pi}{3} \text{ also,}$$
but it's still "pulsing".

Any idea how can I achieve it?

I'd like to be able to control position/speed, but for the moment I'm just trying to make it rotate constantly.

Code : http://pastebin.com/yAfqzVSu

Video : https://youtu.be/ksYnc2J_IFU

BLDC has 12 poles, the PWM has a 62Khz frequency, but the values are updated @ ~20hz

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "pulsing"?

Comment: Well the speed is oscillating. If i'd plot the speed , I'd get some sort of sine wave .

Comment: BLAC or BLDC? they both have different BackEMF characteristics

Comment: Sorry it's a BLDC

Comment: What happens if you try an spin the shaft when it is pulsing? Does it suddenly accelerate and start spinning smoothly? Also, have you got a logic analyser of some sort to see what waveforms you are producing.

Comment: Also, what code are you using to generate the waveforms - how are you performing the commutation. If you just have three PWM generators running 120 degrees out of phase, then at ~60kHz you will be trying to spin the motor at 3600000 RPM.

Comment: I updated the post with more infos !

Comment: How are you determining rotor position?

Comment: Right now it's openloop.

I assumed at this speed, I wouldn't need any sensor to determine when i should commute phases.

 Am i wrong?

Comment: I've never tried to run a brushless motor without some sort of rotor position estimation.  In theory if you have constant speed you can probably keep the control and motor synchronized to some extent but I would be willing to bet the issues you are having are due to bad commutation timing.

Comment: Understood, I'll try to get some back-emf base controller.

Though you've seen operating speed. Do you think it's needed at 10 or 20 RPMs?

Comment: I'd almost say it is worse going that slow than going faster.  Usually you need an encoder or field oriented control to go that slow.  Hall sensors don't work that well below 100 RPM or so (depending on the number of motor poles).

Comment: so a potentiometer or rotary encoder should do the trick ?
I'm going to do FOC in the end, but I need the circuit/components. If you've done FOC I'd be happy to talk a little bit more with you :)

Comment: The reason is that I'm commutating without position information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLDC motors are normally driven in a '6 step' square wave sequence. This *must* be applied in synchronization with the rotor position, or it won't spin.

If you use Hall sensors to control switching then the motor should automatically run at synchronous speed (if the Hall sensors are correctly oriented) but a sensorless motor has be to run 'open loop' until it it picks up enough speed to detect back-emf from the unpowered winding. It will only stay in lock if the speed is increased very slowly, and even then it may jerk back and forth a few times until the rotor aligns with the rotating magnetic field.

At low speed the back-emf is very low and only the resistance and inductance of the windings limits current draw. Start up should be accompanied by a low PWM ratio, to keep the phase current down.

PWM is usually only applied to the low-side (or sometimes high-side) switches, while the other side is switched fully on and off in 6 step sequence. The diagram below shows typical timing of the drive waveforms sent to the switching devices (eg. MOSFETs).

[image]

When the motor is synchronized the voltage waveform across each phase should be a trapezoid shape, as the voltage slopes up and down between activation of each switch. Therefore you don't need to modulate the PWM in a sine wave. In the scope trace below you can see how the 6 steps combine to produce a trapezoid waveform across the phase terminals which is close to a sine wave, even though each individual motor terminal can only go up, down, or open circuit.

[image]

I tried running a brushless CDROM motor with open loop sine wave PWM at very low frequency and PWM ratio. It worked, but was not smooth. Magnetic attraction between the stator and rotor caused a large amount of cogging, which the sine wave drive was too weak to overcome. At higher rpm the movement became smoother due to rotor inertia, but if the speed was ramped up too fast or if any load was applied it would loose sync and stop.

Comment: Thanks ! 

So I assume that it was the cogging torque that caused this effect ( speed is very low as you can see).
However, I'm not sure I understood what I should do. A positive trapezoid wave on each phase ?
In the end I'd like to be able to drive the BLDC in position / speed / torque ( just like a brushless gimbal).

Comment: Brushless gimbals are a special kind of BLDC motor wound with many turns of fine wire to get a high resistance (>=10 Ohms) that can be powered like a stepper motor. They are usually driven with 3 phase sine wave PWM, but cogging still occurs. This is smoothed out by feedback from mechanical motion sensors (potentiometers or gyros and accelerometers). http://sourceforge.net/projects/brushless-gimbal-brugi/ http://evvgc.com/en/evvgc

Comment: Yes, I'm using BLDC gimbal motors, they give lots of torque and low rpm.

Here's a video of my project so far https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoTcR9d1Byg

There's no feedback, but i'm still having trouble with cogging. Right now it's a triangle waveform but I've been told if the motors EMF shape is sinusoidal i should input a sinusoidal waveform. 

Thanks for your help so far :)